# labelling subgraph in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I want to assign unique ID for each subgraph.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' AS row
MERGE (a: Name { name: row.col1 })
MERGE (b: desc { name: row.col2 })
MERGE (a)-[:count {cnt: row.count}]->(b)

RETURN a, b
```

[image]

**Desired output:**

```
 uniqueid    |   group
----------------------------------

  123        |   B, flower, fruit

  234        |   A, tree

  345        |   D, milk
```

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [Graph Data Science Library](https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science) and specifically the [Weakly Connected components](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/wcc/) algorithm. It does exactly what you want to achieve:

> The WCC algorithm finds sets of connected nodes in an undirected
>   graph, where all nodes in the same set form a connected component.

To write back the results you can use:

```
CALL gds.wcc.write({
    nodeProjection:'*',
    relationshipProjection:'*',
    writeProperty: 'componentId'
})
YIELD nodePropertiesWritten, componentCount;
```

And then inspect the results with:

```
MATCH (node)
RETURN node.componentId as uniqueId, 
       collect(node.name) as members
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. Is there a way we can return the label as well. Or query for above according to a label.

Answer (score 0):

In Neo4j v4.x there is a new functionality to accomplish your goal.

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'your file' AS line
RETURN linenumber() AS number,{other items}
```

[Neo4j v4 documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-using-linenumber-with-load-csv)